# Word Search Game Issue

Tags: android, andengine, tile

I am developing a game like word search. I have used AndEngine for this and for displayig grid of words I have used TiledMap. In this game, we need to join letters to make a word as we drag our fingure it will draw line on tiles and make connection between letters. I am able to draw lines vertically and horizontally accurately but as I try to draw line diagonally it goes to the nearby tile and draw line from last touched tile to nearby tile. But as I carefully move to the diagonal tiles it draws line accurately.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

```
e.g.
----------------
|1   2   3   4 |
|5   6   7   8 |
|9  10  11  12 |
|13 14  15  16 |
----------------
```

as shown in above e.g.

I am able to draw line for `"1234" & "159"`, It means all horizontal and vertical positions works accurately.
But for `"963"` its not as accurate as i draw for horizontal and vertical.

```
case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    xMove = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
    yMove = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
    TMXLayer tmxLayer1 =  mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);
    TMXTile tmxTile1 = tmxLayer1.getTMXTileAt(xMove, yMove); 
    tmxTile1.setTextureRegion(mPlayerTextureRegion);

    if (tmxTile1.getTileRow() == 1 && tmxTile1.getTileColumn() == 1) {
    //letter M
        xMove = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        yMove = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
        //yMove = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        if (xMove >= (TILESQUARE * 1)+20 && yMove >= (TILESQUARE * 1)+20) {//added
            yMove = (TILESQUARE * 1) + 30;//gets x-cordinate of center
            xMove = (TILESQUARE * 1) + 30;//gets y-cordinate of center
            Log.i("On Action Move X11", ""+xMove);
            Log.i("On Action Move Y11", ""+yMove);
                          //tmxTile1.setTextureRegion(mPlayerTextureRegion);
            if (!addedAmazeM) {
                addedAmazeM = true;
                System.out.println("You are in (1,1) tile");
                wordArray.add("M");
                HashMap<Float, Float> moveXY = new HashMap<Float, Float>();
                moveXY.put(xMove, yMove);
                //linePath.add(moveXY);
                Point tile11Pt = new Point();
                tile11Pt.x = (int) xMove;
                tile11Pt.y = (int) yMove;
                linePoints.add(tile11Pt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use a circular hitbox. This would enable your finger to pass by the corners but never skip a tile and jump like the horse in chess.

Can you post some code for your fingerchecking?

**Edit*:**
I would be saving a previousTile containing my latest valid tile and then have

```
tmxLayer1.getTMXTileAt(xMove, yMove);
```

return null if I was in between circular hitboxes. 
Example getTMXTileAt:

1. find tile as the function is doing now.
2. find center of tile.
3. Check if my pressed point is within a certain
   "sensitivity-radius" of that centerpoint
4. only count the tile as valid if it is within. If not: my finger is between tiles.

You need to add the lower bounds to both x and y aswell if you still want to do a box approach. I still recomend switching to circular. It is way easier aswell.

Declare a static int for sensitivity ex: 20

then do

```
int tX,tY;
tX = moveX - tileSquareCenterX;
tY = moveY - tileSquareCenterY;
tX *= tX;
tY *= tY;
if(tX + tY < sensitivity*sensitivity)
```

instead of

```
(xMove >= (TILESQUARE * 1)+20 && yMove >= (TILESQUARE * 1)+20) {//added
```

Comment: hi, Problem I am facing is, I want to draw a line on tile 1->6->11->16(it means diagonal). Can you please help me in code example, where I should have to change?

Comment: Yes and by checking with circles you will be able to go diagonally. Try implementing what I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have to large hitboxes for the finger, that there is no space where the finger can move diagonaly without registering a hit on the horizontal or vertical box.

If this is the case it should be easily solved by reducing the size of the "hitbox" by a couple of pixels. This would enable you to drag your finger through corners.

Answer (score 0):

Like Agnfolie said, reduce the size of the hitbox, just not only a few pixels, but try to reduce them to like 50%.

Basicly, only if you draw through the middle of the field it accepts it, and not if you just touch the border.

Comment: means I reduce the range of touch near the centre of tile, is it so?

Comment: you decrease the size of the hitbox towards the center like this:      
|__[hitbox]__|__[hitbox]__|